# Extract presenter notes from PPTx file (powerpoint)

Tags: python, php, powerpoint, python-pptx

Is there a solution in python or php that will allow me to get the presenter notes from each slide in a power point file?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `python-pptx`.

`pip install python-pptx`

You can do the following to extract presenter notes:

```py
import collections 
import collections.abc
from pptx import Presentation

file = 'path/to/presentation.pptx'

ppt=Presentation(file)

notes = []

for page, slide in enumerate(ppt.slides):
    # this is the notes that doesn't appear on the ppt slide,
    # but really the 'presenter' note. 
    textNote = slide.notes_slide.notes_text_frame.text
    notes.append((page,textNote)) 

print(notes)
```

The `notes` list will contain all notes on different pages.

If you want to extract text content on a slide, you need to do this:

```py
for page, slide in enumerate(ppt.slides):
    temp = []
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        # this will extract all text in text boxes on the slide.
        if shape.has_text_frame and shape.text.strip():
            temp.append(shape.text)
    notes.append((page,temp))
```

Comment: Nice job @fusion! :)  Note that `Shape` has a ".has_text_frame" property you can use instead of `hasattr(shape, "text")`.

Comment: @scanny Thanks for the advice!